# Control running GUI applications after Gnome crash

Tags: linux, gnome, gui

My Gnome session hanged, I had to kill `gnome-shell` and create a new Gnome session. But the new Gnome session is empty, while, of course, `ps aux` shows there are all the same programs still running (under the same user), and the new Gnome session does not pick them up. Is it actually possible to make Gnome pick up these GUI applications to be able to control them again?

For example, I have `kate` running in the background, and it has some unsaved text in it. How can I regain control over it in the new Gnome session?

If something like this is not possible with Gnome, is there a GUI that allows this?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to control, graphical apps which have lost connection to your Xorg/Wayland session are essentially gone. You may kill them using one of these two options, the first one is a single-time option, the other one is permanent.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, login, `ps --user username | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' | xargs -t kill`
2. Modify `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` set `KillUserProcesses=yes`, reboot or `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.